# Asp.Net Core 6 Signal-R Connection Takes 4 Minutes to Connect

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0

I've started a new Asp.Net Core .Net 6 project and I have added the signal-r hub with an Angular 13 client.  It connects ... but it takes 4 minutes for the connection to happen.

The app can only support WebSockets.

program.cs

...

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

...

```
app.MapHub<GameHub>("/api/game-hub", options =>
{
    options.Transports = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
});
```

Angular Client

```
  public readonly connection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44405/api/game-hub").build();

    this.connection.start().then(() => {
      this.connectionId = `Success: ${this.connection.connectionId}`;
    }, (error: any) => {
      this.connectionId = `error ${error}`;
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      this.connectionId = `threw ${error}`;
    });
```

The connection hangs for 4 minutes then the

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

method in the hub finally connects.

Any help here?

Comment: What does your browser's DevTools' Network tab say? (ensure "Preserve log" is checked)

Comment: It hangs for 4 min ..  no response... no errors

Comment: Network tab in perpetual wait ... please note ...it does connect...so it works...just a4 min wait

Comment: Pls try to use `LongPolling`, and check the connection time. As you can connect successfully when you used websocket, so I think your code maybe no issue.

Comment: By the way, pls tell us which os version you use ? Win10/11 Home? Professional? Enterprise?

Comment: Is this on localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out.  Websockets won't connect via IIS Express due to other reasons.  My proxy.config.js needed a router to the /hub and a ws:true.  The missing ws:true really caused the delay.